# How to read xml document in CAPL programming?

Tags: can-bus, capl

I have started to explore CAPL Programming. I want to read an input from an XML document but not able to find how to do this. Is this supported in CAPL? If Yes, how do we do it? If No, what are the other type of external files supported in CAPL?

Comment: You can read XML file as a normal text file and write your own parser

Comment: @Swanand...Thanks for the information

Answer (score 0):

There is no build in xml parser in CAPL. You should be able to open a file with the following command:

OpenFileWrite ("Log.txt",2);

Look in CAPL help for more file functions.